# Search for question with exclusively certain tags

Tags: support, tag-search

How do I search for questions that only have certain tags. For example:

If I search [python] the search will come up with any questions that have python as one their tags. This search would show something tagged java,python

How do I search for questions that have only the tag python and no other tags?